# Look for unique values based on identical values in another column (EXCEL)

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns (for simplicity sake). One column is USER and the other column is DATE. I want to add a 3rd column that will display YES or NO.

If a user has multiple different dates, then YES. If user has multiple rows, but the date is the same for both rows, then NO.

Example:

```
USER        DATE        MULTIPLES
John        Feb-3       No
John        Feb-3       No
John        Feb-3       No
Jane        Oct-5       Yes
Jane        Oct-5       Yes
Jane        Nov-9       Yes
David       Jan-3       Yes
David       Dec-8       Yes
```

Is there an easy function that can do this? I've tried to do several IFS, but that's not working very smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$13,"<>"&B6,$C$6:$C$13,"="&C6)>0,"Yes", "No")
```

$B$6:$B$13  is your Date range

$C$6:$C$13  is your User range